# Bash 4.2.46 getopts concatenated short options and resetting OPTIND during processing leads to an infinite loop: How can this be remedied in Bash?

Tags: bash, centos7, getopts

I'm using the following Bash version in a up-to-date CentOS 7 VM:

`GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

The following code performs as expected (take note of **-x -y**):

```bash
set -- -x -y; OPTIND=1; while getopts xy opt; do echo $opt; OPTIND=$OPTIND; done
x
y
```

However, when I combine the two short options to **-xy**, an infinite loop happens:

```bash
set -- -xy; OPTIND=1; while getopts xy opt; do echo $opt; OPTIND=$OPTIND; done
x
x
x ... infinite output
```

The trigger is the `OPTIND=$OPTIND` assignment. If this is removed, the behavior doesn't happen. It feels like there is some hidden substring indexing that is going on:

- `-xy` isn't just index `$1` that `OPTIND` could describe as a single integer
- it feels like index `${1:1:1}` for the **x**
- and `${1:2:1}` for the **y**

Perhaps these are indicated by other getopts parameters not described in the man page. Can anyone shed any light on this that might help me resolve this one issue when writing my wrapper to allow for partial argument/nested getopts handling?

---

***For the curious***: I've implemented some wrapper functions for nested getopts processing. These allow for the partial processing of arguments during which functions might be called that also use the wrapper functions to do getopts processing. I save the `OPTIND` values in a stack array variable and as one pops out of a nesting, the `OPTIND` needs to be reset. It all works quite nicely except for the case where one uses concatenated short flag arguments. (The implementation also makes specifying long options possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can this be remedied in Bash?

Well, by patching the sources. But I wouldn't like to do it, I believe the current behavior is the right one.

You could add an additional function to `getopt.c` and expose it via some special variable in `variables.c` that would allow manipulating `getopts` internal state.

Or even simpler - I see [getopts.def](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/builtins/getopts.def) loadable builtin which you could patch to add some additional option to serialize/deserialize getopts state.

And you can also provide your own implementation of `getopts` as a bash function with your custom semantics and custom state serializer/deserializer.

> Can anyone shed any light on

From [posix getopts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html):

> If the application sets OPTIND to the value 1, a new set of parameters can be used: either the current positional parameters or new arg values. Any other attempt to invoke getopts multiple times in a single shell execution environment with parameters (positional parameters or arg operands) that are not the same in all invocations, or with an OPTIND value modified to be a value other than 1, produces unspecified results.

From that we know:

- [setting OPTIND=1 resets the internal state of getopt ()](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/variables.c#L6195)
- it is **not specified** what should happen if you modify `OPTIND`.

The behavior you are seeing is documented - setting `OPTIND=1` as `$OPTIND` is equal to `1` resets `getopt()`, which results in endless loop, as one would expect. Except for that, bash documentation does not specify what should happen when you modify `OPTIND`. Do not do it. Your expectation that setting `OPTIND` to custom value will affect `getopts` in specific ways is not based on anything. It will not.

> resolve this one issue when writing my wrapper to allow for partial argument/nested getopts handling?

If you are writing your own argument parsing module, do not use `getopts` and do not depend on undefined, unspecified nor implementation defined behavior. I suggest to do it the same way GNU `getopt` does - produce a shell source-able string in separate sub-process, instead of relying on global variables `OPT*` and contributing to spaghetti code.

Do not nest `getopts`, it is not re-entrant and there is no way to affect it's internal state and it uses global variables. `getopts` *sets* `OPTIND`, it is not required to read it, except for the case when `OPTIND` is reset to `1`, in which case `getopts` is reset. Any other value may just be ignored. Just call one `getopts` after another.

Comment: I had hoped that, as with other idioms in Bash, that additional capabilities were available but undocumented and Bash's omission of POSIX's explicit unspecified-results warning gave me hope that this was so. I did take the time since the OP to look at the C code implementation and can confirm your diagnosis. Therefore, it does seem reasonable to implement my own option parsing that will natively handle nested execution in the middle of parsing with predictable results. Fortunately, most of the code I've written can be repurposed to that effect. Many thanks for your response!